# Gutter End without downspout

Tags: gutters

I just built a covered porch. It extends 8+ feet from the house.  The porch roof extends the house roof and one gutter from the house now extends across the porch roof -- ending well away from the foundations. I once saw a diagram of a gutter that ended at the roof-level with no downspout.  It had some kind of end cap that broke up the water from a gushing stream that would gouge a trough in the lawn to a spray that disperses harmlessly.  Can anyone give me more information on what this kind of end cap/dispersal system is called and where I can find them?

Way back they used to use gargoyles for this. I am looking for a less "decorative," more functional version.

[image: Gargoyle]

Comment: This place calls them gutter spouts, which doesn't help much when it comes to googling. http://rutlandguttersupply.com/product/rain-spout-gutter-spout-copper-gargoyle-water-spout/

Comment: As pictured that really won’t prevent erosion either, just slow it down and fan it out a bit.  Also consider that a stream vs drip are two different things.

Comment: That picture depicts a rather robust stream of water.  Only in the most intense rains are you likely to get a stream like that. In a case of a more normal rail the water is more than likely to just drop straight down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be careful “using water” in a creative way. When water is exposed and distributed around your yard, it can erode, flood, create algae, etc. It becomes high maintenance. I especially dislike large chains as downspouts.

Remember the Princess Diana memorial in London. They had to permanent close a portion of it, because they couldn’t control the algae.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Exchange. Your answer has been flagged as not being an actual answer to the question. Can you edit this to make it more focused as an actual answer to the question?  If not this could get deleted for  not being up to site standards.